# How to transfer binary data to C++ application using RabbitMQ from C# application

Tags: rabbitmq

We have a desktop C# application that going to talk to a Windows service in C++. We need to send complex object (with many entities) to this windows service using RabbitMQ. We would like to use binary formatter. but we do not want to use C# binary formatter as C++ service will not be able to deserialize it without .Net libraries. Is there a way to send binary data between C++ and C# using RabbitMQ?

If we copy binary file on hard disk and send the location of this file as an event using RabbitMQ, is this a good idea? This does not seem to be good use of RabbitMQ if we need to copy files to disk and send event using RabbitMQ instead of actual data.

Looking for some guidance from people who have used RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 0):

**You** need to figure out is how to serialize your data so that it can be used by both C# and C++ applications. [Protocol Buffers](https://protobuf.dev/) is a good solution for that.

> Is there a way to send binary data between C++ and C# using RabbitMQ?

Yes, of course. RabbitMQ treats message bodies as opaque binary data so you can send whatever you want.

> If we copy binary file on hard disk and send the location of this file as an event using RabbitMQ, is this a good idea? This does not seem to be good use of RabbitMQ if we need to copy files to disk and send event using RabbitMQ instead of actual data.

This is what Team RabbitMQ recommends if the size of the data is very large or if you will be sending many "large-ish" messages in a short period of time. For instance, if your data is 10MiB, but you only send a few messages per minute, that will probably be fine. You should use [the PerfTest tool](https://perftest.rabbitmq.com/) to simulate your workload. You can specify message size as one of the arguments.